# Generating radio buttons with label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select items from a Select list and generate a Radio list.

Let's say I have these options in a list:

- abc
- dab

I want to print them in a radio list like this:

```
(radiobutton1) abc  
(radiobutton2) dab
```

But right now I am just getting a result like this:

```
(radiobutton1)(radiobutton2) abc dab
```

Here is my code:

HTML

```
 <radio id = MyRadio multiple></radio>
 <label id = MyLabel multiple></label>
```

and Javascript:

```
function btn2Click() {
    var SelectedItems = document.getElementById("MyList");  
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < SelectedItems.length; i++) 
    {
        if(SelectedItems.options[i].selected)
        {
        var RadioSelect = document.createElement("INPUT");
        RadioSelect.setAttribute("type", "radio");
        var RadioText = document.createTextNode(SelectedItems.options[i].text+'\n');
        RadioSelect.appendChild(RadioText);
        document.getElementById("MyRadio").appendChild(RadioSelect);
        document.getElementById("MyLabel").appendChild(RadioText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post HTML with your desired output. Also, note that, although you have jQuery, you are not really using it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a radio tag. It's `input type="radio"`.

Comment: Also, use the `for` attribute of a label to "assign" it to the radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/101/

```
<div class="radioButtons">
    Place Radio Buttons Here
    <br/>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var list = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish'];
    var html = "<input type='radio'/>";
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        $('.radioButtons').append(html + list[i] + '<br/>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Labels work with the `for` attribute. The `for` attribute needs to refer to the `id` of the radio input.

```
if(SelectedItems.options[i].selected)
{
    var RadioSelect = document.createElement("INPUT");
    RadioSelect.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    var RadioText = document.createTextNode(SelectedItems.options[i].text+'\n');
    document.getElementById("MyRadio").appendChild(RadioSelect);
    document.getElementById("MyLabel").appendChild(RadioText);
}
```

Change the label html to:

```
<label id="MyLabel" for="MyRadio" multiple></label>
```

Comment: Don't forget the OP's `<radio>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="myRadioButtons" />
```

**JS**

```
var html='';
$.each(['apply', 'pear', 'peach', 'lime'], function (i, v){
     html += "<input type='radio'/>" + v + '<br/>';    
});
$('#myRadioButtons').append(html);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2a7vp2xm/)**